# how to watermark and convert video to flv with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

how can i watermark and convert a video to flv format with ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the fourth hit on a 'ffmpeg watermark' search: [Add a Watermark to a Video with ffmpeg](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/add-watermark-video-ffmpeg).

```
ffmpeg -sameq -i video1.mp4 -vhook '/usr/lib64/vhook/watermark.so' \
       -f img.jpg video2.mp4
```

Here's the fourth hit on a 'ffmpeg convert flv' search: [Convert to FLV (flash video) with ffmpeg](http://parallaxed.net/article/convert-to-flv-flash-video-with-ffmpeg) (edit: looks like Konamiman beat me to it).

```
ffmpeg -i someVideo.avi -f flv -b 200000 someVideo.flv
```

Comment: Use same quantizer as source (implies VBR)

Answer (score 1):

For converting to flv, see here: http://parallaxed.net/article/convert-to-flv-flash-video-with-ffmpeg

And for watermarking, see for example here: http://linux.goeszen.com/watermark-video-with-ffmpeg.html